# How to stop a running test forcibly

Tags: java, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I am looking for something to stop an ongoing Gatling test forcibly.
Just like stop the test now.

Have gone through Gatling [docs](https://gatling.io/docs/3.2/search/?q=stop%20test) but haven't found anything related to it

Any inputs/help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by stop the test now? Do you want to stop it with interrupt command? Or once a test fails? Maybe on some other scenario?

Comment: @TomerShetah Thank you
Nope, not anything related to test fail or some other scenario.
Just stopping the test, Not sure if it actually stops with interrupt command

Answer (score 1):

It is a roundabout way to do it, but if you wrap the test in a Taurus BZT dockerized test runner, you could kill it with a docker command right?

I suggest that because it is just the simplest way I can think of and you get the added benefits of what Taurus provides.